# Format text with powershell and make a new file with new lines

Tags: powershell

I have some text inside album.txt like

```
some text1 beta glhjkj
gjkkj beta jjkgj jkj
ljj kgj jkg
gjkj bj beta jkgj
```

I want to get a formatted text in a second album2.txt in this way

```
beta glhjkj
beta jjkgj jkj 
beta jkgj
```

only rows that starts with `beta` are allowed

I try to test this .ps1 script from C:\temp but doesn't work

```
# Specifies that this is a PowerShell script
# and that the output data is in text format

[Console ]:: OutputEncoding = [ System.Text.Encoding ]:: UTF8

# Read the contents of the "album.txt" file

$lines = Get-Content .\album.txt

# Change the format of lines starting with "beta" by adding a newline at the end

$formattedLines = $lines | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^beta') {
        "$_`n"
    }
}

# Overwrite the contents in the "album2.txt" file with the formatted lines

$formattedLines | Set-Content .\album2.txt
```

album.txt file is also inside `C:\temp`. 
When I try to run this code nothing happens.

Comment: looking at your desired output it seems you want to match those lines containing `beta` (may not be at the beginning of the line) and remove everything before this word. Could you please clarify on this?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, I want to remove all  text before *beta*

Comment: For example if I change `($_ -match '^beta')` into `{ $_ -match "\bbeta.*" }` it add only rows with `beta` word but don't delete text before beta word. For example i get this output `gjkj bj beta jkgj` but I want only `beta jkgj` and not all words of that row

Comment: I change `{ $_ -match "^beta" }` into `{ $_ -match "\bbeta\s+(.*)" } | ForEach-Object { "beta $($Matches[1])" }` and now it works - thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You could use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) to read your file and match those lines having `beta` and everything after that word:

```bash
& {
    switch -Regex -File .\album.txt {
        '\bbeta\b.*' { $Matches[0] }
    }
} | Set-Content .\album2.txt
```

See https://regex101.com/r/qJRiP6/1 for the regex details.

Comment: I test your code but nothing happens, no filtered text are added in album2.txt - I also try to change `'\bbeta.*'` into `'^beta.*'` but still don't work

Comment: @user3520363 notice the use of `$Matches[0]` instead of `$_` in my answer. The code work as is with the example text you have posted. If it doesnt work for you then you're using a different version of the code

Comment: yes, regex is ok, but don't work as powershell script implementation. Nothing is added in album2.txt

Comment: @user3520363 are you reading and writing the same file by any chance? That would explain why it wouldn't work. If you remove the `Set-Content` part of the code do you see output in the console? If not then please update your question showing how exactly your text file looks because the code as is works fine with the example text you've shared

Comment: I edit now code of webber in this way and now it works `$contents = Get-Content .\album.txt
$filtered = $contents | Where-Object { $_ -match "\bbeta\s+(.*)" } | ForEach-Object { "beta $($Matches[1])" }
Set-Content -Path .\album2.txt -Value $filtered` - problem it was regex implementation in powershell

Answer (score 2):

Okay, there is a simple enough way to do this.

Consider this code:

```
$contents = Get-Content .\album.txt
$filtered = $contents | Where-Object { $_ -match "^beta" }
Set-Content -Path .\album2.txt -Value $filtered
```

The `Where-Object` filters the contents of the `album.txt` file and only include lines that start with `"beta"`.

Now, if you want to add new lines in between the filtered lines, then instead of `Set-Content` you can use :

```
$filtered | Out-File -FilePath .\album2.txt -Append -NoClobber
```

Comment: i try to test your code but doesn't work. I copy-paste exactly but nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

I test user3520363 and Santiago code and this solution is good about regex implementation

```
$contents = Get-Content .\album.txt
$filtered = $contents | Where-Object { $_ -match "\bbeta\s+(.*)" } | ForEach-Object { "beta $($Matches[1])" }
Set-Content -Path .\album2.txt -Value $filtered
```